# Is there a way to make the opacity change in a given timeframe without a button press in lab.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm designing an experiment and I would like the line opacity to change in a given timeframe instead of a button click

```
// Setup event handler
this.options.events['click button'] = () => {
    getLines().forEach(line => {
        line.style.opacity -= step
    })
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: What is `this` (`this.options`/`this.options.events`)?

Comment: And how are we supposed to know this? Or how this might work? Or if there is already a feature for exactly that? -> [How do I write a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use setInterval

```
let opacity = 1;

const reduceOpacity = function(){
  getLines.forEach(line =>{
    line.style.opacity = opacity;
    })
    opacity -= 0.1;
  }

const myTimer = setInterval(reduceOpacity, 1000);
```

I made a fiddle to illustrate https://jsfiddle.net/ninjasoards/bwzg3xfp/

and I added a stop button that fires clearInterval().

CSS ONLY ANSWER

You could also just use CSS for this (and a lot more)

```
.fade-out {
  animation: hide 4s ease-in forwards;
}
@keyframes hide {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ninjasoards/xcbw1gdr/

The left circle fades out and stays faded, and the right circle fades in and out infinitely.

Comment: Well done on the fiddle, clean, constructive, thorough. Wish every answer (including my own) looked that nice.

Comment: Excellent work, will this also work with SVG images created inside HTML? https://jsfiddle.net/codebeginner1/65k9h71x/1/

Comment: Thanks! Yes it will, but also check out the CSS only answer I added. It may better suit your use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `setTimeout` function which will trigger after number of milliseconds specified.

```
  setTimeout(() => {
    getLines().forEach(line => {
        line.style.opacity -= step
    });
  }, 2000);
```